# Capabilitiy Declarations in Desktop Bridge UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, capability

We have a legacy desktop application that is built upon MFC way back and been used till date.

Using Desktop Bridge App Convertor I was now able to create appx for my legacy desktop app and I was able to install it and most of my functionalities are working as expected, except some.

1. How the converted app is working as my legacy app uses registries, which UWP apps will not have access as it is isolated environment? 
   Also I don't see any registries post installation but the features work as expected, how is it done?
2. My legacy app finds certain devices using SNMP communication. Part of my functionalities which are through SNMP are working but one feature (Discovery) which also uses SNMP communication is not working. I doubt on capabilities as there is no scope here to declare while converting. Is that the only reason or any other issues?
3. If capabilities is the issue, how to declare those while doing conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that the converted MFC app lives in a sandboxed environment like a UWP app is wrong. See [this:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

> Aside from the code that you use to light up Windows 10 experiences, your app **remains unchanged** and you can continue to distribute it to your existing Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP user base. On Windows 10, **your app continues to run in full-trust user mode** just like it’s doing today.

The converted app can still access file system and registry. There are some redirections involved. For details of the how DAC handle this, check [Behind the scenes of the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes).

> App packages contain a registry.dat file, which serves as the logical equivalent of HKLM\Software in the real registry...

Comment: Understood.. But in that case I should be able to see the registries created which I don't see now. In normal desktop app installation I could see the registries created but not here.

Comment: Could you also answer my 2nd & 3rd queries

Comment: please check my updated answer. For 2nd, and 3rd query, I don't have idea since I have no experience on SNMP. But doesn't look like an issue caused by restricted permission.

Comment: To declare additional capabilities you would just add them in the appxmanifest.xml post conversion. But this issue is unlikely related to capabilities because your Win32 process runs at full trust and has essentially all capabilities. To understand why your code doesn't work as expected you should debug the converted version of your app and see where/why it fails.

Comment: Fine, thanks for confirming that. I'll proceed my investigation with debugging.